# Error using ghost.py to scrape a page

Tags: python, django, webkit, headless-browser, ghost.py

I'm trying to use ghost.py to scrape a website using a script that works on my local machine:

```
import pdb
from ghost import Ghost
from urlparse import urlparse
import urllib2

...

def scrape(self, request):
    pdb.set_trace()
    page_url = request.DATA.get('url')
    page = urllib2.urlopen(page_url).read()
    original_url = urlparse(page_url)

    print original_url.scheme
    print original_url.netloc

    ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout = 90, display = True)
    page, resources = ghost.open(page_url)

    #use ghost.py to evaluate the javascript on the page
    result, resources = ghost.evaluate("""
                                var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
                                var SrcAlt = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
                                    var src = a[i].getAttribute('src');
                                    var alt = a[i].getAttribute('alt');
                                    SrcAlt.push({"src": src, "alt": alt});
                                }
                                SrcAlt;
                            """)
    #counter = 0
    recs=[]
    for i in result:
        src=None
        alt=None
        try:
            # Gets the image src
            src = unicode(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src')])
            try:
                # Gets the image alt tags
                alt = unicode(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt')])
            except:
                pass
        except:
            pass
```

However, when I add it to my web app, I get the obscenely long error below, and Python crashes. I've read every line of the error and can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be amazing to let me know the first direction to take in making it work! Thank you!!!

```
/Users/fitvalet/wgwt/web/wgwt/views.py(171)scrape()
    -> page_url = request.DATA.get('url')
    (Pdb) c
    http
    www1.macys.com
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.441 python[2475:1e0b] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-945.18/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:328
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.441 python[2475:1e0b] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.442 python[2475:1e0b] (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f56a3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846948 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fcfa4c2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
        4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fd60807 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
        5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b4ae24d -[NSApplication run] + 687
        6   QtGui                               0x00000001086da51d _ZN26QEventDispatcherMacPrivate22ensureNSAppInitializedEv + 99
        7   QtGui                               0x00000001086d9e14 _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 480
        8   QtCore                              0x00000001092918b1 _ZN16QCoreApplication13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 81
        9   QtCore.so                           0x00000001098b27f9 meth_QCoreApplication_processEvents + 164
        10  Python                              0x0000000103e9f5a9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9244
        11  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        12  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        13  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        14  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        15  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        16  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        17  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        18  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        19  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        20  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        21  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        22  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        23  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        24  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        25  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        26  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        27  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        28  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        29  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        30  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        31  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        32  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        33  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        34  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        35  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        36  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        37  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        38  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        39  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        40  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        41  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        42  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        43  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        44  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        45  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        46  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        47  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        48  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        49  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        50  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        51  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        52  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        53  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        54  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        55  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        56  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        57  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        58  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        59  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        60  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        61  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        62  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        63  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        64  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        65  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        66  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        67  Python                              0x0000000103f23a33 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 13636
        68  Python                              0x0000000103f1d4d9 _PyType_Lookup + 1493
        69  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        70  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        71  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        72  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        73  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        74  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        75  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        76  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        77  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        78  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        79  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        80  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        81  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        82  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        83  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        84  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        85  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        86  Python                              0x0000000103ea3018 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 177
        87  Python                              0x0000000103eff7f6 initthread + 1224
        88  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1a7772 _pthread_start + 327
        89  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1941a1 thread_start + 13
    )
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.444 python[2475:1e0b] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-945.18/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:328
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.444 python[2475:1e0b] An uncaught exception was raised
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.444 python[2475:1e0b] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.445 python[2475:1e0b] (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f56a3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846948 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fcfa4c2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
        4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fd60807 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
        5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b4ae30a -[NSApplication run] + 876
        6   QtGui                               0x00000001086da51d _ZN26QEventDispatcherMacPrivate22ensureNSAppInitializedEv + 99
        7   QtGui                               0x00000001086d9e14 _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 480
        8   QtCore                              0x00000001092918b1 _ZN16QCoreApplication13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 81
        9   QtCore.so                           0x00000001098b27f9 meth_QCoreApplication_processEvents + 164
        10  Python                              0x0000000103e9f5a9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9244
        11  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        12  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        13  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        14  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        15  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        16  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        17  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        18  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        19  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        20  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        21  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        22  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        23  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        24  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        25  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        26  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        27  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        28  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        29  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        30  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        31  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        32  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        33  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        34  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        35  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        36  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        37  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        38  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        39  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        40  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        41  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        42  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        43  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        44  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        45  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        46  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        47  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        48  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        49  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        50  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        51  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        52  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        53  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        54  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        55  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        56  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        57  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        58  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        59  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        60  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        61  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        62  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        63  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        64  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        65  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        66  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        67  Python                              0x0000000103f23a33 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 13636
        68  Python                              0x0000000103f1d4d9 _PyType_Lookup + 1493
        69  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        70  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        71  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        72  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        73  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        74  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        75  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        76  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        77  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        78  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        79  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        80  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        81  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        82  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        83  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        84  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        85  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        86  Python                              0x0000000103ea3018 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 177
        87  Python                              0x0000000103eff7f6 initthread + 1224
        88  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1a7772 _pthread_start + 327
        89  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1941a1 thread_start + 13
    )
    2013-09-28 14:38:07.448 python[2475:1e0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f56a3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f846948 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fcfa4c2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
        4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fd60807 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
        5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b4ae30a -[NSApplication run] + 876
        6   QtGui                               0x00000001086da51d _ZN26QEventDispatcherMacPrivate22ensureNSAppInitializedEv + 99
        7   QtGui                               0x00000001086d9e14 _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 480
        8   QtCore                              0x00000001092918b1 _ZN16QCoreApplication13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 81
        9   QtCore.so                           0x00000001098b27f9 meth_QCoreApplication_processEvents + 164
        10  Python                              0x0000000103e9f5a9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9244
        11  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        12  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        13  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        14  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        15  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        16  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        17  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        18  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        19  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        20  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        21  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        22  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        23  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        24  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        25  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        26  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        27  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        28  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        29  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        30  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        31  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        32  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        33  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        34  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        35  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        36  Python                              0x0000000103ea38df _PyEval_SliceIndex + 989
        37  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        38  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        39  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        40  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        41  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        42  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        43  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        44  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        45  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        46  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        47  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        48  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        49  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        50  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        51  Python                              0x0000000103f231a2 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 11443
        52  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        53  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        54  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        55  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        56  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        57  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        58  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        59  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        60  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        61  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        62  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        63  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        64  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        65  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        66  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        67  Python                              0x0000000103f23a33 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 13636
        68  Python                              0x0000000103f1d4d9 _PyType_Lookup + 1493
        69  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        70  Python                              0x0000000103e9f78d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9728
        71  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        72  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        73  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        74  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        75  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        76  Python                              0x0000000103e9df82 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3573
        77  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        78  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        79  Python                              0x0000000103ea3869 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 871
        80  Python                              0x0000000103e9f63a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9389
        81  Python                              0x0000000103e9d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
        82  Python                              0x0000000103ed6d7a PyFunction_SetClosure + 872
        83  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        84  Python                              0x0000000103eb29bf PyMethod_New + 1627
        85  Python                              0x0000000103e956c6 PyObject_Call + 97
        86  Python                              0x0000000103ea3018 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 177
        87  Python                              0x0000000103eff7f6 initthread + 1224
        88  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1a7772 _pthread_start + 327
        89  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b1941a1 thread_start + 13
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
    bin/run-server-dev.sh: line 4:  2473 Abort trap: 6           python web/manage.py runserver "0.0.0.0:$PORT"
    (env)FitValet-MacBook-Pro:wgwt fitvalet$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace back is pointing to `line 14` of `wgwt/web/notification_central/views.py`, saying that it's trying to access the `userprofile` attribute of an `AnonymousUser` object (which doesn't exist).

One fix would be to make sure you're logged in... (so that `request.user` is an `auth.User` object).

Another is to only go down that path if `request.user` is not anonymous, ie:

```
if not isinstance(request.user, AnonymousUser):
    data = get_messages(request.user.userprofile)
```